# Why can't I filter manual pages through grep command?

Tags: grep, man

I'm not sure if something has changed about my system but I find that filtering Unix manual pages through my `grep` command isn't working. Do you know what's wrong?

For example, consider the [jq manual page](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/cff5336ec71b6fee396a95bb0e4bea365e0cd1e8/jq.1.prebuilt#L65-L71) compiled from the following code.

```
.
.IP "\(bu" 4
\fB\-\-slurp\fR/\fB\-s\fR:
.
.IP
Instead of running the filter for each JSON object in the input, read the entire input stream into a large array and run the filter just once\.
.
```

If I want to quickly look up the `--slurp` switch, then I usually filter the `jq` manual page through `grep` like the following terminal session shows.

```
$ man jq | grep -- --slurp
$
```

Notice how nothing is returned. That's weird, the expected result is something like the following.

```
$ man jq | grep -- --slurp
       •   --slurp/-s:
```

That's expected because if I actually run `man jq` command and use the `/` search keystroke, then search for `--slurp`, then that works.

```
# ...
       •   --slurp/-s:

           Instead of running the filter for each JSON object in the input, read the entire input stream into a large array and run the filter just once.
```

I'm guessing there is a problem with special characters but I'm not sure. I tried putting the manual page through `cat` command but that also didn't work. I also tried removing all special characters—see [How to remove all special characters in Linux text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43108359/how-to-remove-all-special-characters-in-linux-text)—but that also didn't work.

```
$ man jq | cat | grep -- --slurp
$
$ man jq | sed $'s/[^[:print:]\t]//g' | grep -- --slurp
$
```

In case this is relevant, please see the following details about my system.

```
$ neofetch --off
OS: macOS 13.0.1 22A400 x86_64
Host: MacBookPro16,1
Kernel: 22.1.0
Uptime: 6 days, 1 hour, 3 mins
Packages: 145 (brew)
Shell: bash 3.2.57
Resolution: 1792x1120@2x
DE: Aqua
WM: Quartz Compositor
WM Theme: Blue (Light)
Terminal: iTerm2
Terminal Font: Monaco 12
CPU: Intel i7-9750H (12) @ 2.60GHz
GPU: Intel UHD Graphics 630, AMD Radeon Pro 5300M
Memory: 10425MiB / 16384MiB
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw the same thing as you on my Mac laptop.  I used `man -P cat` to set the pager to cat rather than setting the `PAGER` or `MANPAGER` environment variables.  As I looked through the man page for `man`, I found this near the end:

```
To get a plain text version of a man page, without backspaces and underscores, try

         # man foo | col -b > foo.mantxt
```

So I tried `man jq | col -b | grep slurp` and I got the lines with `slurp` in them, including the `--slurp` argument lines.

I think the best clue is the phrase in the man page '**without backspaces and underscores**'.  Sure enough if I allow for two characters between each letter of `slurp`, then I see the lines I expect:

```
man -P cat jq | grep s..l..u..r..p
```

Using `od -a` to examine one of the lines with `--slurp` gives me this:

```
0000420   sp   U   s   e  sp   -  bs   -   -  bs   -   s  bs   s   l  bs
0000440    l   u  bs   u   r  bs   r   p  bs   p   f  bs   f   i  bs   i
0000460    l  bs   l   e  bs   e  sp   i   n   s   t   e   a   d   .  nl
```

It's the portion of a line that says  `Use --slurpfile instead.` The renderer apparently uses backspace and printing the letter again to represent bold printing of the string `--slurpfile`.  The backspace and extra letter are what defeated your simple grep commands. (Mine too)

So it looks like piping the man page through `col -b` before `grep` will let you search the output the way you want.